# Why does an IF condition gives an unexpected result in XSLT?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I make a demo of `IF` condition in XSLT.
I want to print a any `text` when `id` match to `node id`. I read document from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256209(v=vs.110).aspx

I used `xsl:if` syntax. But it's not printing the `<p>` tag value.
This is a link to [XSLTTransform for my problem](http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHm/1).

And this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
            XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the
            world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society
            in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new
            society.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

I want to show `jjj` when book id id 'bk101'.

And this is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="book">
            <xsl:if test="@id =bk101">
                <p>jjj</p>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct XPath expression to select all `book` nodes where the `id` attribute of `book` elements matches the value of 'bk101' is

```
book[@id='bk101']
```

So a complete XSLT template would look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="book[@id='bk101']">
    <p>jjj</p>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: why not if condition ? can we apply if condition ?

Comment: Of course you could apply an if-condition instead. But a predicate is shorter. You can transfer the predicate to an `<xsl:if>` if you like. It would look like `<xsl:if test="@id='bk101'"> <p>jjj</p> </xsl:if>`. But what's the use of it making it complicated?

Comment: I am using if in my example with same syntex why it is not working ?

Comment: You were missing the quotes! Those things around your string: `'` `'`. It should have been `'bk101'` instead of `bk101` .

Answer (score 1):

@zx485 is correct that a predicate will probably produce behavior closer to what you'd want in most cases.

That said, your `xsl:if` expression will work -- with one change.  Your current code includes this test:

```xml
<xsl:if test="@id =bk101">
```

The key problem that prevents this from working correctly is quotes -- or rather, that you're missing quotes.

Your `test` above leaves `bk101` unquoted -- so the XPath engine identifies this as an element name, so you wind up comparing the value of attribute `id` against the value of a non-existent element `bk101`.  You need to put the `bk101` in quotes to force the XPath engine to evaluate this as a string instead.  (Use single quotes here, to avoid syntax collisions with the double-quotes defining the `test` expression.)  The fixed line would look like this:

```xml
<xsl:if test="@id = 'bk101'">
```

Running your same code, revised to add the single quotes, in a quick-and-dirty transform on your sample input file produces this output for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>jjj</p>
```